# How to prevent PyMongo from mutating inserted dict?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

If a document doesn't have an `_id` field, MongoDB automatically assigns a proper `_id` field for inserted document, I get that and that's fine for me.

But why pymongo mutates the inserted `dict` by adding `_id` field?
I want to use the inserted dict after it gets inserted and that extra `_id` field is a little bit problem.

I know I can use `dict.pop('_id')` to drop _id field, but if it is a list of documents(for insert_many) then that need an extra effort.

My question is, **is there a way to prevent the inserted `dict` or `List[dict]` being mutated by _id field**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could prevent this by inserting a copy of the dictionary or list of dictionary

```
In [1]: from copy import deepcopy

In [2]: from pymongo import MongoClient

In [3]: data = [{'a': 2}, {'a': 3}]

In [4]: with MongoClient() as client:
   ...:     client.test.collection.drop()
   ...:     result =  client.test.collection.insert_many(deepcopy(data))
   ...:     

In [5]: result.inserted_ids
[ObjectId('5a819d34d99e830381e025b0'), ObjectId('5a819d34d99e830381e025b1')]

In [6]: data
Out[6]: [{'a': 2}, {'a': 3}]
```

Comment: There are other workarounds as well. I am in need for disabling this behavior completely, maybe with a pymongo parameter.